# Sequence spaces dense

Tags: general-topology, lp-spaces

Let $p,q \in [1,+\infty]$, with $p \leq q.$. I have no idea how to prove that, if $q < +\infty$, then $l^p(\mathbb{N})$ is dense in $l^q(\mathbb{N})$, where
$$l^p(\mathbb{N})=\left\{(x_h)\subset\mathbb{R}: \sum_{h=0}^{\infty} |x_h|^p < +\infty \right\}.$$
Would you give me a hint?
Thanks you.

Comment: If $\sum|x_n|^q<\infty$ what is $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=N}^\infty|x_n|^q$?

Comment: That limit is zero

Comment: Right. And that says that if $x\in\ell^q$ then $x$ is the limit of ...

Comment: of a sequence with only a finite number of $x_i \neq 0$

Comment: And a sequence like that is in $\ell^p$. The only place $p<q$ come in is showing that $\ell^p$ is actually a _subset_ of $\ell^q$.